# How to grep the corresponding values between two text files in R?

Tags: r

I have two text files:

f1

```
A   B
sam 23
dam  90
```

f2

```
 G  A  K
43 DQF 65
54 sam 90
56 jay 89
67 dam 43
45 fds 78
```

I would like to add to f1 cols G and K but only for names that I have in A

desired output:

```
 A   B    G    K
 sam 23   54   90
 dam  90  67   43
```

Answer (score 1):

That is better accomplished with `merge`:

```
> merge(f1, f2)
    A  B  G  K
1 dam 90 67 43
2 sam 23 54 90
```

Doing it with `grep` might work, but `merge` is based on `match` and will be more efficient. It automatically matches on columns with shared names in the two first arguments , which is this case is "A"  and is what you wanted. It then adds the remaining columns for the matching rows. (An "inner join" in the language of relational databases.)

Comment: Thanks but yes it is duplicate.can you remove your answer so i remove the question.